# How do you prevent your drupal site from redirecting to external sites via the q variable?

Tags: drupal, url, redirect, phishing

I was wondering how to disallow anyone typing in a url similar to **www.example.com/?q=http://www.evilsite.com**
and instead redirect them to a 404 page or something else. As you can see, this introduces a phishing vulnerability. I know that somehow this is possible as I've seen previous installations redirect

FYI I currently have clean URLs enabled.
My installation is drupal 6.x

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Global Redirect module (described here http://drupal.org/node/768244), are you using it as well?
If yes, you should consider updating it to the latest version, also your drupal core (just in case you haven't done it).

At least, I can't reproduce it on:
- Drupal Pressflow 6.25
- Global Redirect 6.x-1.4 with "non-clean to clean URLs" option checked on.